# Ultrapower construction of ${}^{\ast \ast}\Bbb R$

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

Suppose, we want to add positive elements that are smaller than all positive elements in ${}^{\ast}{\Bbb R}$. One way to do this, as shown in this  [master’s thesis](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~lenth/thesis.pdf), is to construct sequences of elements in ${}^{\ast}{\Bbb R}$ that range over ${}^{\ast}{\Bbb N}$ and find an ultrafilter on ${}^{\ast}{\Bbb N}$, ${}^{\ast}{\mathcal U}$.

<strike>Can we find such ultrafilter  ${}^{\ast}{\mathcal U}$? Do we need to require all sets in ${}^{\ast}{\mathcal U}$ to be internal sets? Or we have to live with a cheap version, ${}^{\ast}\mathcal {P}{(\Bbb N)} \cap {}^{\ast}{\mathcal U}$?</strike>

The author want to eliminate the possibility of constructing an positive element in ${}^{\ast}\Bbb R$ that is strictly smaller than all positive elements in ${}^{\ast\ast}\Bbb R$ by excluding $\Bbb N$ from ${}^{\ast} \mathcal U$. But it seems to me it's far from enough.  ${}^{\ast} \mathcal U$ shouldn't contain any element with the cardinality of $\Bbb N$. I think what he need is a uniform ultrafilter in which all elements have the cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$. Is it right?

Comment: I don't understand your question fully. Can't we just let $\mathcal F = \{A \subseteq {}^*\mathbb N \mid \text{ there is a finite set $E$ such that } {}^*\mathbb N - A = \mathbb N \cup E \}$. Then $F$ is a filter, take an ultrafilter ${}^*\mathcal U$ containing it. Then ${}^*\mathcal U$ is an ultrafilter on ${}^*\mathbb N$ not containing $\mathbb N$ as wished.

Comment: @martini:Both $\Bbb N$ and ${}^{\ast} \Bbb {N} \setminus\Bbb N$ are external. If we exclude $\Bbb N$, then ${}^{\ast}\mathcal U$ must contain ${}^{\ast} \Bbb {N} \setminus\Bbb N$, right?

Comment: Yes, but the author of the thesis you linked remarks that we need to exclude $\mathbb N$ to get what we want.

Comment: @martini: Thank you for your comment. I feel less puzzled now.The author want to eliminate the possibility of constructing an positive element in ${}^{\ast}\Bbb R$ that is strictly smaller than all positive elements in ${}^{\ast\ast}\Bbb R$ by excluding $\Bbb N$ from ${}^{\ast} \mathcal U$. But it seems to me it's far from enough.  ${}^{\ast} \mathcal U$ shouldn't contain any element with the cardinality of $\Bbb N$. I think what he need is an uniform ultrafilter in which all elements have the cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I didn't dive into the thesis this deep, but this can be achieved, I think. Let $\mathcal F = \{A \subseteq {}^*\mathbb N \mid |{}^*\mathbb N - A| < |{}^*\mathbb N|\}$. This is a filter, take an ultrafilter ${}^*\mathcal U$ containing it. ${}^*\mathcal U$ cannot contain a set of cardinality less then $|{}^*\mathbb N|$.

Comment: @martini: Thanks for the information.

Comment: I don’t think that he needs a uniform u.f.: he just needs to be sure that no member of $\mathscr{U}$ is countable. Any u.f. extending the co-countable filter on ${}^*\Bbb N$ should do nicely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see. Uniform ultrafilter is too strong, unless we assume continuum hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need such a thing as **R? To define a *Riemann integral over infinitesimal intervals. And why would one want to do that? Because that is one way to integrate over fractals, where, for instance, the Cantor set is 2^omega intervals of length 2^-omega. Now integrate your function over each of these intervals, and add them all up.

Answer (score 0):

$^\star\mathbb{R}$ only satisfies countable saturation, so to defeat it it suffices to take an index set of cardinality the continuum in the ultraproduct construction, so using $^\star\mathbb{N}$ is fine.  It is not entirely clear to me why one needs such a $^{\star\star}\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is you are doing calculus, except that your functions are already defined on the hyperreals. Then you would need numbers smaller than any hyperreal. Ergo hyperhyperreal.

Comment: I understand that, but practically speaking this can be done within a single $^\star\mathbb R$ suitably defined.  I don't think one needs the iterated construction. I recall seeing a discussion of this in one of Terry Tao's blogs.  If you are interested I can try to look it up.

Comment: Well, sure a single $\mathbb{R}**$ could be used practically. But that would be boring.

Comment: Infinitesimals are never boring.  See http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03023265?LI=true# :-)

Comment: I have had occasion to make use of the iterative construction -- I had to iterate something like four times to make the intuitive argument I wanted to make. (although technically it was semi-algebraic, so I just needed real closed fields rather than hyperreals, but the same idea)

Comment: @Hurkyl, that's interesting. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's been long enough I don't recall the details, but it was the sort of thing where I had to make a sufficiently small perturbation to a function to change a double root into two single roots, so I make an infinitesimal one. But now I have two roots that are infinitesimally separated, and I need to pick a third point that is sufficiently near one but not the other... and other similar things. At each step, it was far easier to just add a new infinitesimal, rather than try to argue how "close" was "close enough".